# get date in thunderbird message via Dolphin send-to

Tags: date, thunderbird

I have successfully created a working desktop file that send (one or more) attachments to thunderbird, with from, to fields and with, as a body, a file html.
This is the file content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
Actions=SendToMailRcp
Encoding=UTF-8
MimeType=application/octet-stream
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
X-KDE-Submenu=allega a

[Desktop Action SendToMailRcp]
Name=posta elettronica...
Exec=thunderbird -compose "attachment='$(echo %F | sed 's/\\ \\//,\\/\\//g')',to=[some-account],subject=[my-subject],message='path/to/myfile.html',from=[some-my-account]"
Icon=thunderbird
```

Now I'd like to add a function for the date, for inserting autmatically today date.
I tried with javascript, but javascript is not working in e-mail; I tried with php (message='http://localhost/path/to/file.php'), but if I try to get a php file in thundebird body I don't get anything.

How can I, if possible, get the date in body message?

Comment: Do you mean the date as part of the mail headers (TB should add that automatically if missing), or do you want to put it into the body? `date -R` (or `$(date -R)` in your applied case) will give you the current date in standard format, where to go from there depends on where you need it.

Comment: I mean put (the date) into the body. Thank you! Adding as you said "$(date -R)" I get the week day ("Mon"), I'd like to get day-month-year. A second problem: with your code I cannot see what follow the code (i.e. "\n partenza:")

Comment: Using "body=arrivo: $(date) \n partenza:" I get the date, tough in format imperfect, but nothing after the code (no: " \n Partenza:")

Comment: When I try to use $(date +"%d-%m-%Y") I get as "%d" not the day, but the current directory of the attachment, and as %m "--", only %Y works (2018). Can someone help me? Why this thunderbird's misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: this is the code (see my question above for the whole code):
Exec=thunderbird -compose "attachment='$(echo %F | sed 's/\ \//,\/\//g')',to=[some account],subject=[some subject],body=arrivo: $(date **"+%x"**) \n partenza:,from=[some account]"